# Genitive case – Which word determines the gender?

Tags: genitive

Genitive case is confusing me. Let's consider the following two sentences:

> Das ist das Auto **deiner** Schwester.
>
> Das ist die Frau, **deren** Bruder krank ist

In the first sentence, it is taking **the gender of the second word**, `Schwester` to write `deiner`. If it took first one, `Auto`, it would have been `deines`.

In the second sentence, it is taking **the gender of the first word**, `Frau` to write `deren`. If it had taken the second one, `Bruder`, it would have been `dessen`.

There seems to be no consistency in which word is used, to determine what pronoun to use. Am I missing a rule??

Comment: Thanks, corrected. Only 2 examples are enough to show the problem then.

Comment: I still didn't get the problem. The car **of your sister** and the woman **whose brother**. There are two different words with different meanings, placed in differently formed phrases. So there is no rule how to use one single word in which case. You should go into more details about your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both your examples it is using the gender of the person that the (grammatical) objects belong to.

Example 1: Who owns the car (*Wessen Auto ist das?*) -> your sister (*deine Schwester*) -> *[...] das Auto **deiner** Schwester*

Example 2: Who has a sick brother (*Wessen Bruder ist krank?*) -> the woman (*die Frau*) -> *[...] die Frau, **deren** Bruder [...]*